# How to redirect different subdomains to applications running on different ports with nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, reverse-proxy, lets-encrypt

I have 2 nodejs applications running in my EC2 instance at PORT 3000 and 1337. What I want to achieve is

> admin.mydomain.com

should be redirected to the application running on PORT 1337 and

> mydomain.com [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)

should be redirected to the application running on PORT 3000.

With my current nginx configuration I am getting a 502

```
  map $subdomain $subdomain_port {
  default    3000;
  www        3000;
  admin      1337;
}

server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name _;
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
server_name ~^(?P<subdomain>.+?)\.historydiaries\.com$;

location / {
proxy_pass http://localhost:$subdomain_port;
proxy_redirect off;
}

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/historydiaries.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/historydiaries.com/privkey.pem;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;

ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:5m;
ssl_session_timeout 1h;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security “max-age=15768000” always;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using two different nginx conf

Comment: Nginx matches conf with server_name. So if u have exact entry of domain it will pick that conf.

Answer (score 0):

I will go with separate Nginx vhost configuration.

One for [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) and another one for admin.mydomain.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain_access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

and

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name admin.mydomain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/admin.mydomain_access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

This just simple vhost configuration. You can add Let's Encrypt later when you need.

Comment: It would be great if you can mention how it would look with letsencrypt setup too. Thanks